# A question about lattice visible point in the plane

Tags: number-theory

I'm wondering if the following question has been taken as a research or not, or anyone has any interesting idea that can be shared.

In planar coordinate plane, a point $(x,y)$ is called "visible" from point $(a,b)$ if the segment joining them contains no other integer point except $(x,y)$ and $(a,b)$ themselves. 
Given a square nxn, for each lattice point $K$ inside of the square, denote by $F(K)$ be the set of points which are visible from $K$.

My question is, is there anyway to find the point $K$ such that #$F(K)$ is max (#$F(K)$ is the number of elements of $F(K)$)

Thanks for any idea from you guys!

Comment: This is related to the density of "visible" points in the integer lattice, $6/\pi^2$, as discussed in [this MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/151706/what-fraction-of-the-integer-lattice-can-be-seen-from-the-origin).  My guess is that the symmetry of the square makes points near its center better prospects than points near the periphery.

Comment: yepp I have the same idea. I'm trying to do some small cases first but feel like there is no pattern.

Comment: It may be helpful to embed the problem of visible points in a square grid into the seemingly more general problem of a rectangular grid.